# Tool to auto generate DML stored procedures for all the tables in my schema -MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, dml

I was looking for a tool which can can auto-generate the DML stored procedures (Insert, Update, Delete, Select) for my MySQL database from the schema.

Comment: Why not do it yourself. Just loop through `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and write out the sql statement.

Comment: @ConradFrix : Thanks for that suggestion. Its bit tough because there are 100+ tables. I am looking for a tool or script which can create the sp for me then I will update it according to the business rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I haven't used it with MySql, only SQL Server, [Codesmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) can generate CRUD stored procedures based off of tables within the database.

The tool provides customizable templates, and it looks like someone in the community created [a template for generating MySql procedures](https://web.archive.org/web/20150307015306/http://community.codesmithtools.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Components-PostAttachments/00-00-02-22-89/StoredProcedureMYSQL.cst)

Comment: The file has been deleted, would you please suggest another link.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan Thanks for the heads up on the broken link... I've updated with a different MySql template link that is valid.

Comment: The link to mysql template is again missing, I searched for the same on official website but no luck, can anyone pls help? I know this question is pretty old, but just went through this.

Comment: @AniketBhansali https://web.archive.org/web/20150307015306/http://community.codesmithtools.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Components-PostAttachments/00-00-02-22-89/StoredProcedureMYSQL.cst

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson Thanks for help, It saved my day, it had few problems so here is an update to it http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=98748963069867055977